# Cannot create cache directory ! help me solve this when create laravel project with composer

Tags: 16.04

```
smmm@smmm-linux:/var/www/html$ composer create-project laravel/laravel test
Cannot create cache directory /home/smmm/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/smmm/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/smmm/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
```

Comment: @George: Sorry, maybe I just don't know the subject matter enough, but why is this off-topic?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I am so sorry was looking at `composer` and didn't see the main content or pay attention to it...retracting

Comment: Please Simon post the results of `lls -al /home/smmm/.composer/cache/`

Comment: @George: Ok, that's fine, but please pay more attention in the future. ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874482/cannot-create-cache-directory-or-directory-is-not-writable-proceeding-withou Please check that link to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to your path i.e that follows `/home/smmm/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org`, you have to try these commands to solve your problem.

- Change the group permission for folder
  **sudo chown -R smmm /home/smmm/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org**
- Change the files folder
  **sudo chown -R smmm /home/smmm/.composer/cache/files/**
- And then for the whole composer's directory change the permission
  **sudo chown -R smmm /home/smmm/.composer**

Best Regards