# "Cannot create cache directory /home/<user>/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache"

Tags: permissions, php

newbie here.

I was trying to install MISP in my Ubuntu, following this installation guide:[INSTALL.ubuntu1804.txt](https://github.com/MISP/MISP/blob/2.4/INSTALL/INSTALL.ubuntu1804.txt)

When it comes to this instruction:

```
# Once done, install CakeResque along with its dependencies if you intend to use the built in background jobs:
cd /var/www/MISP/app
sudo -u www-data php composer.phar require kamisama/cake-resque:4.1.2
```

I got this:

```
Cannot create cache directory /home/akatiubuntutest/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/akatiubuntutest/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
./composer.json has been updated
Cannot create cache directory /home/akatiubuntutest/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/akatiubuntutest/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0)
    Downloading: 65%^C
```

I tried the solution here [Cannot create cache directory ! help me solve this when create laravel project with composer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919796/cannot-create-cache-directory-help-me-solve-this-when-create-laravel-project-w):

```
sudo chown -R <user> /home/<user>/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org
```

But (well, logically, since it is yet to be created) I got this:

```
chown: cannot access '/home/<user>/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/': No such file or directory
```

I've already installed PHP and the dependencies:

```
# Install PHP and dependencies
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php php php-cli php-gnupg php-dev php-json php-mysql php-opcache php-readline php-redis php-xml php-mbstring
```

Right now, I'm not sure what I missed doing.

Comment: It might be a permissions error with something earlier in the path (like maybe `~/.composer` is owned by `root` or something). Try running `sudo chown -R $USER. ~` to ensure everything in your home directory is owned by you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it seems to me the group information is missing in your command

```
sudo chown -R <user> /home/<user>/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org
```

Shoud be

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> /home/<user>/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org
```

But to avoid other permission issues, I would rather advise:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> /home/<user>/.composer/cache
```

(you'll need access to other folders in there)
and

```
sudo chown <user>:<group> /home/<user>/.composer
```

To make sure your user has permissions enough on the global composer folder. Mind the missing recursion so the user don't own keys created by root. 
If you need to find out the group:

```
groups <user>
```

Answer (score 26):

if anyone pass through here, this is shorter solution:

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.composer
```

Comment: That removes the  exception but on lightsail whatever i do composer update/install it always kills the command.